# Calculating tangent at point x = a

Tags: trigonometry, tangent-line

The equation of the tangent to a curve $y = f(x)$ at a point where $x = a$ and $y = f(x)$ at which the derivative $f'(x)$ exists and is finite, is,

$$\frac{y-f(a)}{x-a}=f'(a)$$

Find the equation to the tangent for the following curve $y^2 = 4ax$, normal, sub-tangent and sub-normal.

So what I have tried for tangent was the following:

$$y = \sqrt{4a^2}$$
because $x=a$,
then plugging this into the equation above:
$$\frac{y - 2a}{x-a} = 2  \\ y-2a = 2x-2a \\ y = 2x$$

Then for the normal, instead of $f'(a)$ I use instead $-\frac{1}{f'(a)}$, this gives me
$$\frac{y-2a}{x-a}=-\frac{1}{2} \\ y-2a = -\frac{x-a}{2}$$

However, the solutions tell me I should have $x-y+a=0$ for tangent and $x+y=3a$ for normal, respectively.

For sub-tangent I have $\frac{f(a)}{f'(a)}$ and sub-normal I get $f(a)f'(a)$

Therefore,

sub-tangent $ = \frac{2a}{2} = a$, sub-normal $ = 2a \times 2 = 4a$, however, these are shown to be $(2a, 2a)$ respectively according to solutions.

Much help is appreciated in correcting the maths!

Comment: You do not have $x=a$ when you calculate $f'$, and the value for $f'(a)$ you plug in is wrong.

Comment: @Henriksupportsthecommunity Can you explain a little more by what you mean?

Comment: @Henriksupportsthecommunity ok so for when $x=a$ I should take the derivative first and plug in the value $a$ for $x$ thus giving me $a^{-1}$ however,  I still do not get the answer. For some reason the derivative should be equal to $1$.

Comment: The confusion arises from the fact that $a$ s used for two different things in your formulas and the problem description, and you don't treat them different enough. Ignoring the formula for the tangent, from $y^2=4ax$ you get $f(x)=y=\sqrt{4ax}$. Differentiating that you get $f'(x)=\frac{4a}{2\sqrt{4ax}}=\sqrt{a}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}$. where $a$ is just some constant that appears in the definition of the function you work on..

Comment: I suggest you calculate the tangent line (and others) at some point $x = c$ instead of specifically at $x = a$ (which is a parameter in the definition of the curve). Only after have calculated this general tangent line, should you replace the generic $c$ with the specific value $a$. Also, $y^2 = 4ax$ has *two* branches, and thus two points of tangency for any given $x$-coordinate, and two tangent lines. Did the book really just ignore the existence of the second branch?

Comment: @PaulSinclair Its a fairly old A-levels books that briefly skims over the mathematical details. So I largely have to figure out the exercises myself. Which is why I use MSE to help me out! :)